# JAXB XML to Object

Tags: jaxb

I am trying to unmarshal the data of XML. If XML structure is like the structure given below then How to made the class to print both the values of attribute as well as element. I want to unmarshal it and consider that Vehicle is one class and Accessory is another class and accessory is made as attribute to Vehicle class. I want the class structure so that the object, I get after unmarshalling will be used to get both the values "Wind Screen" and "My wind screen is broken".

```
<Vehicle>
        <Accessory type="Wind Screen">My wind screen is broken</Accessory>
</Vehicle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your XML, `Accessory` cannot be `attribute` but `element` to the `Vehicle`.

With below class, you can unmarshall the `Vehicle` object and retrieve the values from `Accessory` class. Or you can overrride `toString()` method of `Vehicle class` to print the values of Accessory attribute `type` and `content`.

**Vehicle.class**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Vehicle", propOrder = {
})
public class Vehicle
{

    @XmlElement(name = "Accessory")
    protected Accessory accessory;

 // other elements

}
```

**Accessory.class**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Accessory", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
public class Accessory
{

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")
    protected String type;

 // getters and setters ommitted for brevity.

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.